# Convert String to CGFloat in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift, how can I convert a String to CGFloat?

I tried:

```
var fl: CGFloat = str as CGFloat
var fl: CGFloat = (CGFloat)str
var fl: CGFloat = CGFloat(str)
```

all didn't work

Comment: Do you need to handle international users? (For example, in Germany, the comma is used as the decimal separator.) If so, consider using `NSNumberFormatter`, which will employ the device's internationalization settings to handle numbers in the user's preferred format.

Comment: thanks but internationalization is not an issue here

Answer (score 150, accepted):

If you want a safe way to do this, here is a possibility:

```
let str = "32.4"
if let n = NumberFormatter().number(from: str) {
    let f = CGFloat(truncating: n)
}
```

If you change `str` to "bob", it won't get converted to a float, while most of the other answers will get turned into 0.0

**Side note**: remember also that decimal separator might be either comma or period. You might want to specify it inside the number formatter

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.decimalSeparator = "." // or ","

// use formatter (e.g. formatter.number(from:))
```

Comment: None of the other answers handle international user input. If this string is input from a user, a `locale`-specific answer such as this (or `NSScanner`) should be used.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of localization. (Let's face it, it's something even the best programmers often don't consider.) But you're right.

Comment: It seems like there is no `NSNumberFormatter` in Swift 4.0.

Comment: `NumberFormatter` for Swift 4

Comment: CGFloat(truncating: n)

Answer (score 32):

As of Swift 2.0, the `Double` type has a failable initializer that accepts a `String`.  So the safest way to go from `String` to `CGFloat` is:

```
let string = "1.23456"
var cgFloat: CGFloat?

if let doubleValue = Double(string) {
    cgFloat = CGFloat(doubleValue)
}

// cgFloat will be nil if string cannot be converted
```

If you have to do this often, you can add an extension method to `String`:

```
extension String {

  func CGFloatValue() -> CGFloat? {
    guard let doubleValue = Double(self) else {
      return nil
    }

    return CGFloat(doubleValue)
  }
}
```

Note that you should return a `CGFloat?` since the operation can fail.

Answer (score 17):

You should cast `string` to `double` and then cast from `double` to `CGFloat`, Let try this:

```
let fl: CGFloat = CGFloat((str as NSString).doubleValue)
```

Comment: Going from float to CGFloat can cause a loss in precision (tried it with 0.57). Going from double to CGFloat maintains the correct value.

Comment: @Maxwell for now. In the future there may be additional floating-point types to consider. Additionally, there's a good reason `CGFloat` exists in place of `float` and `double`: it runs faster on 32-bit processors. Relying on IEEE 64-bit float to maintain a correct value is shortsighted at best.

Answer (score 16):

This works:

```
let str = "3.141592654"
let fl = CGFloat((str as NSString).floatValue)
```

Comment: The drawback of this is that `(str as NSString).floatValue` gives 0 for strings it doesn't understand, like "bob". This could be a feature or a bug depending upon your requirements. I wouldn't use this method if I was accepting untrusted input. Instead, I'd use `NSNumberFormatter` or the like.

Answer (score 11):

**Simple one line solution:**

```
let pi = CGFloat(Double("3.14") ?? 0)
```

Answer (score 9):

in Swift 3.0

```
if let n = NumberFormatter().number(from: string) {
  let f = CGFloat(n)
}
```

or this if you are sure that string meets all requirements

```
let n = CGFloat(NumberFormatter().number(from: string)!)
```

Answer (score 7):

While the other answers are correct, but the result you see will have trailing decimals.

For example:

```
let str = "3.141592654"
let foo = CGFloat((str as NSString).floatValue)
```

Result:

```
3.14159274101257
```

To get a proper value back from the string, try the following:

```
let str : String = "3.141592654"
let secStr : NSString = str as NSString
let flt : CGFloat = CGFloat(secStr.doubleValue)
```

Result:

```
3.141592654
```

Comment: fair enough, I prefer yours

Comment: actually, I'll wait for upvotes to decide who gets the answer. thanks though.

Answer (score 6):

You can make an extension that adds an init to CGFloat

```
extension CGFloat {
    
    init?(string: String) {
        
        guard let number = NumberFormatter().number(from: string) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        self.init(number.floatValue)
    }
    
}
```

Use it like so `let x = CGFloat(string: xString)`

Comment: Be careful with NumberFormatter as behavior depends on current Locale

Answer (score 3):

**in Swift 3.1**

```
if let n = NumberFormatter().number(from: string) {
   let fl = CGFloat(n)
}
```

**or:**

```
let fl = CGFloat((str as NSString).floatValue))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a work around, but you can cast it as an NSString, then get the float value, then initialize a CGFloat from that value. Example:

```
let str = "1.02345332"
let foo = CGFloat((str as NSString).floatValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question. There is not in fact *any* pure Swift API for converting a string that represents a CGFloat into a CGFloat. The only string-represented number that pure Swift lets you convert to a number is an integer. You'll have to use some other approach from some other library - for example, start with Foundation's NSString or C's (Darwin's) `strtod`.

Comment: facepalm. I appreciate the answer, but any hack to do this? (ie code). coming from javascript it's like going back to the 18th century here.

Comment: `NSNumberFormatter` is also a possibility, though I doubt it's as efficient. Unsafely: `CGFloat(formatter.numberFromString("23.4")!)`.

Comment: yes it does, vacawama's answer. in case u weren't paying attention stackoverflow IS my man.

Comment: Right. But you see what I mean; you're shifting into the whole vast mechanism of Cocoa / Foundation in order to do this. It isn't "pure" Swift. I think their reasoning was: well, Cocoa / Foundation and C _are_ there, and they are not going away, so we don't need to build a big language like JavaScript or Ruby.

Comment: @matt Interesting, I never thought of Foundation as not being "pure" Swift, but I see your point and agree.

Answer (score -3):

```
let myFloatNumber = CGFloat("4.22")
```

Comment: It would be much better if you edit your answer to explain how this solves the original problem and is better than the existing collection of answers.