# How to convert NSTextField value to CGFloat

Tags: swift, cocoa

```
let countY = CGFloat(self.textbox1.stringValue); //NSTextField value= 1024.231234
if let image:CGImage = CGDisplayCreateImage(CGMainDisplayID(), rect: CGRect(x: countX, y: countY, width: 1, height: 1))
        {
```

and i got the error

> Expression type '@lvalue String' is ambiguous without more context
>   Thanks

Comment: Please add more information. The question is also *ambiguous without more context*.

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27595925/8441876) SO answer for how to best convert a string into a CGFloat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGFloat` doesn't have a string initializer.

Just get the `doubleValue` from the text field rather than the `stringValue`

```
let countY = CGFloat(self.textbox1.doubleValue)
if let image = CGDisplayCreateImage(CGMainDisplayID(), rect: CGRect(x: countX, y: countY, width: 1, height: 1)) {

}
```